# ffmpeg: Encoder (codec amr_nb) not found for output stream #0:1

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this command to convert `flv to 3gp`

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.flv -ar 8000 -b:a 12.20k -ac 1 -s 176x144 out.3gp
```

And it's giving this error

```
Encoder (codec amr_nb) not found for output stream #0:1
```

I have searched for `amr_nb` packages on `yum` but didn't able to find it.

I'm on CentOS 7

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

I'm not sure what's missing.

**Edit:**

I followed this guide https://s3bubble.com/installing-ffmpeg-on-centos-6-6-in-usrlocalbin/ + alijandro's advice.

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 22.04: `sudo apt install sox libsox-fmt-all && sox input.mp3 output.amr-nb`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ffmpeg installed in your system didn't support encoder `amr-nb` which is the default encoder for `3gp` format.

See if you can find in the encoders list

```
$ ffmpeg -encoders |grep amr_nb
```

You can try

1. use h263/aac as the output encoder, add the option `-vcodec h263 -acodec aac`
2. or build ffmpeg with `amr-nb` support

   - get opencore source from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr
   - compile the source and install to `/path/to/opencore-amr`
   - get the source of ffmpeg
   - configure ffmpeg with the options

     ```
     $./configure --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
     --enable-libopencore-amrwb \
     --enable-version3 \
     ...
     --extra-cflags="-I/path/to/opencore-amr/include" \
     --extra-ldflags="-L/path/to/opencore-amr/lib"
     ...
     # more configure options
     ```
   - compile and install ffmpeg, then your command will work

Comment: AMR is an audio codec, so the choice of vcodec doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks alijandro that was it.